# Яндекс карты API 3. Добавление метки на карту после поиска

Tags: yandex-maps-jsapi

Есть карта на сайте. Есть строка поиск. По поиску получаю результат с координатами, могу центрировать карту по этим координатам. Но не могу понять, как мне поставить метку по адресу, введенному в поле поиска.

Comment: А в чём проблема? Выполнили поиск, получили координаты, добавили метку с этими координатами, пример же есть у Яндекса https://yandex.ru/dev/jsapi30/doc/ru/examples/cases/placemark